# Move search filter location (Volusion)

Tags: javascript, search, filter, e-commerce, volusion

What is the best way to move the search refinement filters at the top of my [Volusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volusion_%28company%29) store?

I would like the top filter to be where the "Price: Low to High" & pages numbers are, but unfortunately Volusion said that these are hard coded in and cannot be moved.

Regardless, I would at least like to able to get "Find by Pricing", "Find by Brands", "Find by ABS" and "Find by strand" to be just above the "immovable filters". They are just a bit too out of sight.

A sample is at:

```
http://zsvae.zbfps.servertrust.com/category-s/1985.htm
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone usign this as reference, or having the same issue, I had to do the following: Change CSS for search_refinement_filters to have position:absolute !important; and add margin-top:100px; This was a rough fix, your margins will have to be adjusted to suit your specific needs. I'm going to employ a consistent header layout so the look and spacing is uniform through the store.

If you have some pages using category.css that have a header, or description, or header image, you'd either have to make individual CSS rules for those pages, or do that. I want a uniform look on pages where products are present, so this will suffice for me.